# Merging two managedObjectContexts

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have two managedObjectContexts(MOC): a temporaryMOC and a persistedMOC. If I initialize an entity in the tempMOC and the user decides to save, I save and merge the changes into the persistedMOC and save. In which MOC are now those entities? If the user start a new file, there will be now two entities in the tempMOC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MOCs is only a scratchpad with which you can create, update, delete and retrieve NSManagedObjects.

If you've got two objects as a result of a save operation - it means you've mistakenly created two entities that are saved with the merge.

Could you show us the code in which you create an object?